# Adding custom variable for callback url in packaged Connected App (Canvas)

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, canvas, callback, canvaslifecyclehandler

how can we add additional parameters to callback so that we can determine the SF org which is calling the our server.

We were to do this for Canvas url via Adding Custom Setting (List) and adding this via Customizing Canvas app cycle

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_customizing_app_lifecycle.htm

How can we achieve this for callback of connected App.

Comment: anybody can help here? ... Dont see much help from this forum . Where else can I check ?

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you help here?

Answer (score 0):

We weren't able to figure out how to get a variable into the connected app settings, however we were able to determine the SF org of the user in our connected app by hitting the "identity" endpoint you'll get back from the REST API: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009ANxIAM